# Error with php queries

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to access two tables in a database, one agents and the other properties. When i click a link on a previous page, it brings me to this with the id in the address bar. I can't understand why I keep getting this error message: **Warning: mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\practice\details.php on line 16**

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $agent ="SELECT agentId FROM properties WHERE id='$id'";
    $agentQuery ="SELECT * FROM agents WHERE agentId='$agent'";
    $agentResult=mysql_query($agentQuery);
    $agentNum=mysql_numrows($agentResult);
```

I already have this code working:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM properties WHERE id = '$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
```

Comment: *Never* assume `mysql_query` succeeded.  You should *always* be checking to make sure the query worked.  `if($agentResult === FALSE){ die(mysql_error()); }`

Comment: Can you *please* write a better, more descriptive title?  What does this have to do at all with phpmyadmin?

Comment: What value is `$agent`?

Comment: You should not use the mysql_* functions anymore. They are marked as deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli_* instead.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: I was trying to assign `$agent` the id related to the link clicked.

Comment: @Jessicam93: Then either get the ID first, and pass that to the 2nd query, or use a subquery: `SELECT * FROM agents WHERE agentId=($agent)`.  Actually, better yet, use a JOIN: `SELECT agents.* FROM agents JOIN properties ON agents.agentId=properties.agentId WHERE properties.id='$id'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's condense your query code down to a single statement:

```
$agentResult=mysql_query(
  "SELECT * FROM agents WHERE agentId='SELECT agentId FROM properties WHERE id='$id''"
);
```

That is not a valid query.

Add that to the fact that you're not actually checking the return value from `mysql_query()` to see if it was successful or not, and you have the error you've provided.

*Yadda yadda* SQL injection *yadda yadda* `mysql_*` functions deprecated *yadda yadda* learn to use PDO or mySQLi.

Ignoring all those things I just said, your code should be more like:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$agent_q = "SELECT agentId FROM properties WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
if( ! $rs = mysql_query($agent_q) ) {
  die(mysql_error());
} else if( mysql_numrows($rs) == 0 ) {
  echo('no agent by that ID');
} else {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
  $agent = $row['agentId'];
  $agentQuery ="SELECT * FROM agents WHERE agentId='$agent'";
  if( ! $agentResult = mysql_query($agentQuery) ) {
    die(mysql_error());
  }
  $agentNum = mysql_numrows($agentResult);
}
```

Or simplify your query with:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM agents a INNER JOIN properties p
  ON a.agentID = p.agentId
WHERE p.id = $id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query probably is getting an error, so the result(`$agentResult`) is `false`. Because of this the error message is saying "*boolean* given".

Try to embrace your `mysql_numrows` with a `if` statement:

```
$agentResult=mysql_query($agentQuery);

if ($agentResult)
{
    $agentNum=mysql_numrows($agentResult);
}
else
{
    echo mysql_error(); // To show the query error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `$id=<someid>`, this

```
$agent ="SELECT agentId FROM properties WHERE id='$id'";
$agentQuery ="SELECT * FROM agents WHERE agentId='$agent'";
```

resolves to this:

```
$agentQuery ="SELECT * FROM agents WHERE agentId='SELECT agentId FROM properties WHERE id='<someid>''";
```

..which fails to execute.